# How can i insert a massive amount of data From a DataBase into a TableWidget in a optimized way?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a PushButton that when clicked, it displays the data of the DataBase to the TableWidget by runing the funcion `add_values`, and it works fine if you have a few thousands of rows, But let's say you have milions of rows, it's very ineficiente because I am using the method `feachall()` appending the DataBase's data into a varible and using a for loop to insert the data into the TableWidget.

here is my code.

```
DataBase = sqlite3.connect("DataBase.db",check_same_thread=False)
cursor = DataBase.cursor()

class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(1, 5)

        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(list('ABCDE'))


class AppDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(600, 600)

        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.table = TableWidget()
        self.button = QPushButton("add items")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.add_values)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)


    def add_values(self):
        
        cursor.execute("select * from Peaple")

        data = cursor.fetchall()

        self.table.setRowCount(len(data))
        self.table.setColumnCount(5)

        for i in range(0, len(data)):
            for j in range(0,5):
                self.table.setItem(i,j , QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data[i][j])))



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
demo = AppDemo()
demo.show()
app.exit(app.exec_())
```

i looked at DB Browser SQLite to see how it handles this when you Browse Data, and the DB Browser SQLite only loads the data when you actually  see it and not 'Pre-loads' everything in advence.

[Illustrating what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la6tr.gif)

Is there a way to do something like this in pyqt or is there another solution?

notice, i can't use thread cause even so it's gonna take some time to append the DataBase's data into the varible.

Comment: Can it be displayed in pagination, that is, only a part of it is displayed at a time, such as a hundred items?

Comment: Don't use `fetchall` use `cursor` as an iterator instead.

Comment: ppipg  ,  it does , is there some tutorial or documentation teaching how to do this?

Comment: Qt models natively support [`canFetchMore()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#canFetchMore) and [`fetchMore()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore), and if the model implementation supports it, the loaded/shown data is initially limited to a specified number of rows (defaults to 255) and further data is then loaded/added when the view scrolls near the bottom. Remember that QTableWidget is a higher level class that is normally not intended to be used for complex/large models; you should consider using the QtSql module with QSqlTableModel set on a QTableView instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want this ?

```
    #get cursor on app start
        cursor.execute("select * from Peaple")

    def add_values(self):        
        
        needed = 2
        data = cursor.fetchmany(needed)

        column = 5
        self.table.setColumnCount(column)

        rowCount = self.table.rowCount()

        try:
            for i in range(0, needed):
                for j in range(0, column):
                    self.table.setItem(rowCount-1+i, j, QTableWidgetItem(str(data[i][j])))
                self.table.setRowCount(rowCount+i+1)

        except IndexError:
            print("=====================")
            print("IndexError Because There is No Data to Get From Table")
            print("=====================")
```